# CASE statement to IIF statement

Tags: ms-access-2010, case, iif-function

I have this CASE statement that I need to convert to IIF in Access:

```
Case When sfrstcr_pidm is not null Then 'A' WHen sfrstcr_pidm <> '' Then 'A' Else Null End as StudentStatus,
```

Would this be the correct way to convert to IIF?

```
IIF ([sfrstcr_pidm] is not null, ‘A’, IIF([sfrstcr_pidm] <> ‘’, ‘A’, Null))
```

Comment: Rather than nesting statements, you could use `OR`?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to convert a `Case` statement to Access SQL is using the [`Switch`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) function. This takes multiple arguments, and uses `if` ... `then` ... `elseif` ... logic. It doesn't have an `else` option, but `elseif true` works around that.

Using this function, your code would become the following:

```sql
Switch(sfrstcr_pidm is not null, 'A', sfrstcr_pidm <> '', 'A', True, Null)
```